# Access "Start up" folder from CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, special-folders

How can I get the path of the start up folder from a batch file? The only way I found was to look in the registry but I don't think thats possible with CMD.

Comment: what startup folder ? which is in programs menu ?

Comment: @Sudhakar Start > All Programs > Startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set `STARTUP` to the location of the startup folder:

```
for /F "skip=4 tokens=3*" %%j in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup"') do set STARTUP=%%k
```

(`skip=4` is for XP, use `skip=2` for Windows 7. I don't have Vista to try the command there)

Also available (change the value after `/v`):

```
Common AppData
Common Programs
Common Documents
Common Desktop
Common Start Menu
CommonPictures
CommonMusic
CommonVideo
Common Templates
Common Favorites
Common Startup
Common Administrative Tools
```

Comment: Hmm... doesnt seem to work, I wrote echo %STARTUP% and it wrote "ECHO is OFF..." and I tried cd %STARTUP% and it showed the current directory.

Comment: try just `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup"` from the command line - the 4th line is what we are after. the 3* is a kludge to get around the fact delimiters are horrible to work with on this command - the 3rd item on that line should be `REG_SZ`, and the 4th will be everything after that

Comment: Yeah, just putting in that line worked, how would you put this into a variable, because then you could just do %var:~75,% to get to the important part (75 isnt the exact number, I didn't count yet :P)

Comment: ok. seems in XP it's `skip=4` and in win7, it's `skip=2`. count the lines from the output from the `reg query` command, and skip that number of lines less one

Comment: Yes, skip=2 worked but the reg query command had 4 lines when I did it by it's self

Comment: on an 80 column display, 2 of the lines wrap to the next line, but the system still sees them as one line

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP you can access like this

```
CD %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: You need quotes around it, because of the space in "Start Menu", and it will only work in an english version of Windows

Comment: Hmm well it will be good if you place in single quotes. but now days it allowed in all new systems. Its worked in my system.